# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_settings_dictionary'

Tags: boxsdk

```
from boxsdk import JWTAuth, Client
auth = JWTAuth.from_settings_file(settings_file_sys_path=box_config_json_path)
client = Client(auth)
print(client.user().get())
return client
```

Error in Lambda:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_settings_file'

Tried installing boxsdk[jwt] instead of just boxsdk.

Added boxsdk[jwt] in requirement.txt
or
pip install "boxsdk[jwt]" (Because of '[' used quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
from boxsdk.auth.jwt_auth import JWTAuth
```

Instead of

```
from boxsdk import JWTAuth
```

This resolved issue in lambda.

> pip install boxsdk[jwt]

only resolved the issue in my local and not in my lambda.